# Taking the Vector out of Some

Tags: scala

In my code, after an API call, I am getting

`Some(Vector(72981, 72982))`.

I need to get the vector out of `Some` so that I modify the vector. Tried many things but no result.

Comment: "Tried many things but no result." Did that include reading the documentation (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Some@get:A) or pretty much any tutorial on Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `map` you can modify what's in the `Option` (i.e. the `Some` in this case)

```
Some(Vector(72981, 72982)).map(vector => // do something with vector)
// Some(modifiedVector)
```

this will return the modified vector inside an `Option`.

If you want to extract the value from the `Option`, you can use `getOrElse`

```
val v = Some(Vector(72981, 72982)).getOrElse(/* a fallback value */)
```

or a match

```
val opt = Some(Vector(72981, 72982))
opt match {
  case Some(vector) => // do something with vector 
  case None => // vector doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: "do something with vector" sparked my brain cells. Thanks.